# NullPointerExcepction for TextView.setText() when called inside onPreExecute()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

It is stated in [d.android.com for onPreExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) that it runs on the UI thread before `doInBackground(Params...)` so it should easily access the `TextView` and perform `setText()` method from the `Activity` from which it was `executed()`.

But here in the below codes the `loading` **TextView** is privately declared inside the class `SplashScreen` that extends **Activity**. Inside the `onCreate()` it is linked with the TextView widget of the UI. But when `AsyncTask` extended class `Atom` the function `onPreExecute()` is executed which throws a `NullPointerExcepction` for the statement `loading.setText("Loading...");` executed inside it.

Here the code

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements AnimationListener{
...
TextView loading=null;
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


            try {
                a = (Atom) new Atom().execute(null,null,null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                finish();

            }
...

 loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

 ....

 }

 public class Atom extends AsyncTask<RSSFeed, Void, RSSFeed>{

    private RSSReader reader;
    private RSSFeed feed = null;
    private String uri = "http://website.com/feed/";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

       super.onPreExecute();
      //------------problem----area-------------------
       loading.setText("Loading...");
      //------------problem----area-------------------  


    }

        @Override
        protected RSSFeed doInBackground(RSSFeed... arg0) {


            reader = new RSSReader();

              try {
                feed = reader.load(uri);
                Log.d("rss", feed.getTitle());



            } catch (RSSReaderException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              return feed;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prg.cancel();

            t(result.getTitle().toString());

        }


        }
 }
```

The stack:

```
03-09 10:50:12.793: W/System.err(14214): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 10:50:12.813: W/System.err(14214):    at in.edu.ss.er.splash.SplashScreen$Atom.onPreExecute(SplashScreen.java:158)
03-09 10:50:12.827: W/System.err(14214):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-09 10:50:12.833: W/System.err(14214):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-09 10:50:12.833: W/System.err(14214):    at in.edu.ss.er.splash.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:45)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have a TextView with the id of `R.id.textView2` in your xml?

Comment: where are you calling this AyncTask  ?

Comment: please add your xml code also.

Comment: in the main UI thread SplashScreen (edited the question !)

Comment: I think you are calling async task before declaration of textview.so its getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to initialize `TextView` before executing `asyntask`. Like following.

```
try {
    loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    a = (Atom) new Atom().execute(null,null,null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    finish();

}
```

I don't know this is correct or not, This my guessing, So, Please let me know what happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

just initialize your text view before calling AsyncTask. do something like this

```
 loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 try {
            a = (Atom) new Atom().execute(null,null,null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your textview before then call asynctask. Change your code into following-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            try {
                a = (Atom) new Atom().execute(null,null,null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                finish();

            }
 }
```